# How to change FlutterLogo color?

Tags: flutter

Earlier there was a `colors` property which used to change the default color for the Flutter logo. But seems like it is removed. So, how can I change the Flutter logo color?

```
FlutterLogo(
  colors: Colors.red, // Error (now)
)
```

Comment: does this answer your question - https://fluttercentral.com/Articles/Post/1097/FlutterLogo_Widget

Comment: @Reign Nope, the constructor they're using have `colors` property in it, which is now removed.

Comment: From official document. https://flutter.dev/brand  Don’t alter, distort, or modify the Flutter trademarks in any way. This includes varying the spelling of the “Flutter” name, or displaying the Flutter logo with color variations or unapproved visual elements.

Comment: @chunhunghan Google changed their polices!

Answer (score 0):

The `FlutterLogo` widget doesn't have any properties to change its color but you have kind of a workaround by using the widget `ColorFiltered`.

### Code

```dart
class StylizedFlutterLogo extends StatelessWidget {
  final ColorFilter colorFilter;
  final double? size;

  const StylizedFlutterLogo({required this.colorFilter, this.size});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  ColorFiltered(
      colorFilter: colorFilter,
      child: FlutterLogo(size: size),
    );
  }
}
```

### Sample 1

```dart
StylizedFlutterLogo(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
    0.2126,
    0.7152,
    0.0722,
    0,
    0,
    0.2126,
    0.7152,
    0.0722,
    0,
    0,
    0.2126,
    0.7152,
    0.0722,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0,
  ]),
)
```

[image: sample 1]

### Sample 2

```dart
StylizedFlutterLogo(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
    0.393,
    0.769,
    0.189,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0,
  ]),
)
```

[image]